# How to get list items from another site collection in remote event receivers

Tags: csom, remote-event-receiver, spcontext

I have created a remote event receiver which is working fine. Now there is change in functionality such that, we have to bring some items from another site collection with in same web application, in remote event receiver.

I am creating context inside updated event of RER as below

```
using (ClientContext rootCtx = new ClientContext(rootSiteUrl))
{
}
```

But it is giving me 401 unauthorized error. 
My urls are like below

```
https://(server)/Teams    
https://(server)
```

Comment: You need to use an access token to authenticate with SharePoint, since the RER is Remote.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an access token to authenticate with SharePoint.  You have to have the access token appended to the request headers for the `ClientContext`.  If you already have the access token, you create the `ClientContext` as follows:

```
ClientContext clientContext = null;
try 
{
    clientContext = new ClientContext(targetUrl)
    {
        AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Anonymous,
        FormDigestHandlingEnabled = false
    };
    clientContext.ExecutingWebRequest += (sender, eventArgs) => eventArgs.WebRequestExecutor.RequestHeaders["Authorization"] = $"Bearer {accessToken}";
    // use clientContext
} 
finally
{
    clientContext?.Dispose();
}
```

If you are using the helper classes that are added by default, then you can use the method that the TokenHelper class exposes:

```
var context = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(HttpContext.Current);
using (var clientContext = TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAccessToken(targetUrl, context.UserAccessTokenForSPHost))  // or use context.AppOnlyAccessTokenForSPHost if you want app permissions
{
    // use clientContext
}
```